# Another OpenGL Z Fighting question : Can I enforce a fragment shader to draw last?

Tags: android, opengl-es, fragment-shader

I'm doing this on Android but I've not had much success so far.

I have a 3D mesh, something like a terrain/height map.

I then have a plane that clips horizontally through the mesh (think of it as ground level) and this mesh can be moved up and down.

Obviously, there are lots of instances of z-fighting I'm seeing, especially if any triangles on the Terrain are the same normal as the ground plane so they end up being exactly co-planar.

All I want is to simply, say 'if theres zfighting, just draw the ground plane second'.

I've tried GL Depth Function GlLequal, GLLess etc but they don't seem to have any affect (do I need to also enable something else)?

Is there anyway inside the fragment shader to give it a priority order? Or do I need to set the Depth function *after* rendering the Terrain mesh first, or is there something I need to do in between the calls to render the Terrain and then render the Ground/Clip plane?

Answer (score 0):

Z fighting is caused by precision differences caused by float rounding - so literally the planes are swapping which is closest. With D24 depth this is really hard to avoid - if you look at a lot of games with decals rendered using geometry they float them above the surface to avoid almost-coplanar geometry.

There are really two ways I can think of to solve this one.

Render the ground plane using a post-process pass, reconstructing the depth by reading the depth buffer in a shader. This requires splitting into a second render pass, or something like `ARM_shader_framebuffer_fetch_depth_stencil` to read back in the same pass for a tile-based GPU.

For more modern APIs (Vulkan, DX) the best way to solve this is to use reversed fp32 depth buffers. The variable float precision works to counter the 1/Z scaling so you get relatively uniform spacing of encoded depth values, and the higher precision is enough to solve most depth fighting issues. The problem is that this only really works with 0 to 1 clip space encoding, and OpenGL ES uses -1 to 1.